# Can this happen in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

This is a Google Drive that "anyone on the internet with this link can edit". I am not an owner of the Drive. Can it happen that (1) I posted a file there, (2) someone deleted it, and (3) there are no log of my posting the file and someone deleting the file?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is plausible if:

1. You upload a file over a shared drive
2. A Direct member of the Shared drive, like a Manager or Content Manager deleted it (or moved it to the trash).
3. Generally shared drive logs are only available or visible to the organization that is the owner of the shared drive itself, and those logs or information can only be viewed by a Super Admin.

The key thing here is the fact that shared drives are only available if you have a Google Workspace account as suggested over their help center [article](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351) . By the moment you upload a file to a shared drive, the file no longer is owned by you, the organization that has the shared drive becomes the owner.

Which could explain why you might not have the logs, because those are only available for the organization as suggested in this [article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696).

Edit:

Adding a screenshot[image] with activity of the permissions of the folder and the upload of a file that was deleted:

Personal account activity (not showing upload or deletion of the picture):[image]

Edi 2:

Updating sample on how the logs show the upload of a file to the shared drive
[image]

Comment: Yes it is a logical analysis. I think what happened is: (1) Organization A has the Google Workspace, (2) Mr. B has an account in Organization A and created a shared drive (shared for everyone), (3) I posted the file, someone has deleted it, and (4) Can it happen that Mr. B does not have logs of these activities?

Comment: The moment the file was uploaded to the shared drive, the owner will always be the organization, not the original user who did it. I have tested it myself with my shared drive and a personal account with a folder from a shared drive with anyone with the link, if you were never a direct member of the shared drive, and only upload a file to that folder, there are no records (for the personal account activity info), and the only one that can see activity of the file I deleted it that was upload it, is a member of the shared drive.

Comment: Mr B should be able to check the activity of that folder showing the upload and deletion of the file, let me edit the response and add the example.

Comment: Then this is another question. This time I have the Google Workspace. I have a shared Google Drive folder. I can go to "Audit and Investigation" and see "Drive Log Events." Then how can I tell whether this login is mine or not. I access with the same IP.

Comment: It should give you the details of the user who uploads it, it requires a login to be able to upload data to a shared drive, so this can be audited. At least it would show the email address (actor) of the user action over the shared drive or any changes being done over the Drive. I can add the example with one more update over the response.